# Tag a friend when post content - Facebook API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using Facebook PHP SDK to post a message on Facebook and tag that message to my friend.

After setting all the initial setup for Facebook 
I tried.

```
$friends = $fb->get("/me/taggable_friends");
$friends= $friends->getGraphEdge()->asArray();
 $id = $friends[0]['id'];
 echo $id;
$post = $fb->post('/feed',array('message'=>'hi','tags'=>$id));
```

I am getting the $friends and correct $id.  But  although message is posted But not tagged to my friends. And the response from the above request is id of the posted message(post). So everything seems correct.

have Facebook removed this functionality.

Btw my app is not reviewed and approved by the Facebook yet but i am using that app only for myself so that should not be the issue.

I can't find out the issue myself. I would really appreciate some help. Thanks !

Comment: What does it say in the description for the `tags` field in the docs …?

Answer (score 1):

Your app not publish yet, so it not shown in <del>your/</del>your friend's timeline.

Your friend who you are tagging should in one of your app's admin, developer or tester if your app is not publish yet.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reply but I am app admin who is trying to tag the friends. So it should work without publishing the app

Comment: You will see message posted on your timeline but not on your friend's  timeline. Because your friend who you tagged not in any role of your app so the post not show on your friend's timeline.

Comment: em... did I miss your point?
Your message not tagged your friend or it isn't show on your friend's timeline?

Comment: Hi, I made one of my friend developer and another  a tester, And tried to tag them both when posting content on facebook . But still can't able to tag them. Have you tried that method yourself, Because i tried everything it doesn't seem to work now

Comment: I just tested it again and found that someone cannot be tagged.
But it is 'taggable friend', isn't it.?

Comment: Yes. they are 'taggable friends' .